# How to find out all pixels in lines drawn by user in Java Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, line

I've been trying to get all the pixels of a line which is being drawn by a user into an array.

I will later try to make an analysis of this line so it is very important that I don't miss any pixels. With the code I use currently it misses quite a few pixels. The problems should be in the way that graphics creates lines and not individual pixels. The pixels that are set, are saved into the `image1Pixel` array. Here is my `myMouseDragPaint` function in which I save the lines into the array.
Does anyone know how I can change this so I won't miss any pixels?
If you need any additional information regarding this question, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you,

Miza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving only line vertexes in your code, missing all pixels between them:

```
image1Pixel[currX][currY] = 1; // line vertex
G.drawLine(prevX, prevY, currX, currY); // this draws a whole line, no just two vertex points
```

You need to either:

- interpolate all pixels on that line. E.g., popular algorithm is [Bresenham's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)
- or get an image and read pixel color directly from it

Also, note that lines don't cover single pixels (except exactly vertical or horizontal ones). So second option will work better for you, because you will not repeat drawing math after graphical library.

Comment: I've added link to algorithm. But what went wrong with reading pixel color's??

Comment: Thank you very much for you fast answer... I will look into Bresenham's algorithm and post the results.

Comment: Thanks again... I got it to work. I used http://onyx.boisestate.edu/~tcole/cs498/spr04/ammeraal/Bresenham.java to find out how to set this up exactly.